# Вывести из базы данных записи с совпадением хотя бы одного слова

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос. В базе данных есть таблица **tovar** .
В этой таблице есть ячейка `name` .
Туда записываются названия товаров. 
Хочу сделать поиск по товарам.

Дело в том что название товара может быть вида *уголь черный* или *черный уголь сырой* .

И если делать выборку из базы по названию товара, при вводе слова *сырой уголь* - ничего не найдет.

каким запросом можно делать выборку из базу с совпадением хотя бы одного слова в ячейке `name` таблицы **tovar** ?

Буду очень благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: если "в лоб" то `name like '%сырой%' or name like '%уголь%'` или использовать "полнотекстовый поиск" (в гугл так и вбивать)

Comment: @Mike так не пойдет. предположим что слова для запроса идут в переменной **$abc = "сырой уголь";**

Comment: А вы строку на слова разбейте explode или preg_sprit и создайте запрос на основе них.

Answer (score 1):

Если совпадение одного слова, то

```
$str = "слово для поиска"; // осторожно! необходима экранизация

$query = "SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE tovar.name LIKE '%$str%'";
```

Если для нескольких, то, в данном случае

```
$a = 'сырой уголь купить';  // поисковая строка
$vars = explode(' ', $a); //  получаем массив из слов

$combine = array_map(function($elem) {  // добавляем оператор LIKE
    return "tovar.name LIKE '%$elem%'";
}, $vars);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $combine); // генерируем запрос

var_dump($query);
```

Результат

```
SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE tovar.name LIKE '%сырой%' OR tovar.name LIKE '%уголь%' OR tovar.name LIKE '%купить%'
```

Какие проблемы могут быть:

- Будет долго искать в таблицах `InnoDB`
- Если в названиях много общих слов, то будет находить не то, что необходимо
- Нет экранизации, обязательно необходимо фильтрировать входящую строку, чтобы не получить `SQL-инъекцию`
- Если строка будет пустой - будет ошибка в `SQL` запросе

Для таких целей необходимо использать поисковой движек, вроде `ElasticSearch` и `SphinxSearch`

Comment: а при совпадении двух или более слов этот запрос подойдет?

Comment: @Денис вы ведь можете проверить данный запрос в MySql, если слово будет `уголь`, то найдет все записи, где в `name` встретится `уголь`